# Clarifying the behaviour of NSLayoutManager & NSTextContainer with respect to vertical layout?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nsview, nslayoutmanager

## Code Sample

I have a `NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer & NSTextStorage` as properties in a custom `NSView` (not a TextView) initialized in `awakeFromNib()` as follows:

```
    textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: self.attributedString)

    layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    textContainer = NSTextContainer(containerSize: NSMakeSize(self.frame.size.width, 1))

    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer)
```

The vertical `containerSize` of the `NSTextContainer` is deliberately set to 1 to see if it has the expected effect of hiding the text being rendered - it does not! It is making **NO** difference in the rendering of this text in the view - which is the subject of the question!

In `drawRect` I include the lines below to draw the text:

```
let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer)
self.lockFocus()
layoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0))
self.unlockFocus()
```

## Findings

1. It appears best to work with your custom view in a flipped co-ordinate system like the `NSTextView` else I feel like I'm going to be in for a world of pain! Irrespective of this, NSLayoutManager always starts drawing its text internally in a flipped co-ordinate system (just like `NSTextView`)
2. The `containerSize.width` property of `NSTextContainer` has the following effect: it is binding on a line level for all levels including the first (I know it's obvious but stick with me...)
3. The `containerSize.height` property of `NSTextContainer` has a curve-ball: it will NOT be binding on the first line **even if** the containing view does not have the room to display it vertically BUT will be binding on subsequent lines

*it took me a long time to come to this hypothesis about `containerSize.height` because I was only drawing one line! *

## Question

1. Are my conclusions regarding `NSTextContainer` correct?
2. What is the best way to control text drawing from a vertical perspective? I am wanting to place my single line of the text at the bottom of the view (and not have it floating at the top as in the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTextContainer` has a `containerSize` property. The layout manager is laying out the text within that container. Presumably, the container is what is logically being positioned at (0, 0) in your view, but the text is laying out from its top. So, the container has slack.

You could resize the container based on the rect returned from `-[NSLayoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:]` to size it to fit.

---

Update:

I think code like this in your `drawRect()` should work for what you want to achieve:

```
layoutManager.ensureLayoutForTextContainer(textContainer)
var rect = layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)
rect.origin.x += 2
rect.origin.y = NSMaxY(self.bounds) - NSHeight(rect) - 4

let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer)
layoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint:rect.origin)
```

Comment: The result of `layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)` is coming out at (0,0) - naturally that's not going to help things. Strangely, even though I set my textContainer.containerSize to this (0,0) it does nothing to the ultimate view rendered!?

Comment: Stranger still: the layout of my view seems independent of the `textContainer.containerSize` in general. Have just been playing with a few starting values.

Comment: `-usedRectForTextContainer:` does not perform layout. You would have to ensure layout before getting a meaningful value from it, using `-ensureLayoutForTextContainer:`. Not sure about the other stuff.

Comment: Thanks. By calling `ensureLayoutForTextContainer(...)` I am now getting sensible values for the `containerSize`. However, still not changing how it renders.

Comment: FWIW `layoutManager.setLocation(NSMakePoint(2, 2), forStartOfGlyphRange: glyphRange)` seems to work in bringing the text down to start at the bottom of the view. Using (2,2) because (0,0) actually cuts off a little text.

Comment: Could your layout manager have more than one container, such that the one you have a reference to is not the first? That would explain why changing its size doesn't seem to affect layout.

Comment: I am now replicating the problem in a simplified example with a single view - just to avoid complications. `println(self.layoutManager.textContainers.count)` yields 1 when called in `drawRect`

Comment: Done a lot more work honing in on the problem and have hypothesised an explanation above...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that does work. I am now figuring out how to take a lot of the processing above out of the drawRect method to optimise for scrolling...but that is another question!